# Discrete Metric Space is Not Separable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Why is it that for the metric space $(X,d)$ where $X=\Bbb R$ and $d$ is the discrete metric, then $(X,d)$ is not separable? Does this have something to do with $\Bbb R$ being uncountable? Can someone prove why this is true?

Answer (score 5):

In the discrete metric all subsets are closed, thus $\operatorname{cl} S=S$. So the only dense subset is $\Bbb R$ itself, which is not countable.

Comment: Why is it that in a discrete metric all subsets are closed?

Comment: If the definition is through the distance $d(x,y)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\ne y\\ 0&\text{if }x=y\end{cases}$, because $B_d(x,1/2)=\{x\}$ and, thus, $X\setminus S=\bigcup\limits_{y\in X\setminus S} B_d(y,1/2)$ is open.